# Show $L = \int_a^b\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that, if the function $y=f(x)$ continues in the interval $[a,b]$, then the length of the arc is defined as:
$$L = \int_a^b\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dx$$

---

My first problem comes not to be able to define a length for $[a,b]$

Comment: It would help if you expressed more clearly your question.

Comment: I just need a demonstration on why the length of the arch is equal to $\int_b^a\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dx$

Comment: get to $\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}dy$

Comment: See the link in my answer. By the way, your limits of integration should be swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how rigorous you would like to be. There is a formal way, and then there is the more intuitive way. I will show the intuitive way (because the formal way, as I have seen it, is some pages long).

Consider the curve $\gamma: x = x(t), y = y(t)$. Then the length of a small element $ds$ of $\gamma$ is just 
$$
   ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 +  
                                    \left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2} dt
$$ 
Then the total length $L$ of $\gamma$ is simply the sum of all small elements:
$$
  L = \int_a^b \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 +  
                                    \left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2} dt
$$
Since $y = f(x)$ and $x = t$, this yields
$$
  L = \int_a^b \sqrt{ 1 + f'(x)^2} dx
$$
The formal proof goes by determining the Riemann sum of the total length on $[a,b]$, and other jazz, but it is the same idea as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the length of the curve, e.g. consider $f(x) = x^2$ on $1 \le x \le 2$. You have to find the length along this curve, and your result tells you it is given by
$$
L = \int_1^2 \sqrt{1 + (2x)^2} dx = \int_1^2 \sqrt{1+4x^2} dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just take $f(x)=1$ in your definition. The resulting value will be the length of this curve, that is, the length of the interval $[a,b]$.

It seems I have mistaken the question. A proof of the arc length formula is found here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx